# Human Face Divine

Tags: syntactic-analysis, poetry

I recently read that there is a grammatical construct known as a *Miltonic Structure*, after John Milton. It said that the structure consists of an *adjective + noun + adjective*, like "human face divine" from Paradise Lost, book III:

> "Or flocks, or herds, or human face divine;"

I searched but found no singular construct such as this called Miltonic Structure. Are you familiar with this structure? Is it called this? Does it have another name?

Comment: Haven’t heard of it, but it sounds like Blake rather than Milton:

'Cruelty has a human heart /  
And jealousy a human face, / 
Terror the human form divine,/  
And secrecy the human dress.'

Comment: Paradise Lost, book III: "Or flocks, or herds, or human face divine;"

Comment: Thanks. Long time since I read it. Blake probably had that in the back of his mind as he was writing.

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of *adjective + noun + adjective* forms around. It was no problem to find, for example, [foreign minister designate](http://www.mofa.gov.lr/content.php?sub=22&related=9&res=22&third=22) without really thinking. But in Op's example, the two adjectives are by most interpretations mutually exclusive. I doubt there will be many of those unless they're being helped along by a bit of poetic licence.

Comment: Irrelevant sidebar! *adjective + pronoun + adjective* occasionally occurs, because almost any adjective can occur quite naturally both before and after the pronouns *something, someone,* and *somebody.* Thus *little something extra*, *elusive someone special*, and so on. (Adjectives also occur after *anything/one/body* and *everything/one/body,* but apparently not before, except *just anything* —is *just* an adjective there? Adjectives can also occur after *nobody* and *nothing* but I couldn’t find an *adjective + negapronoun + adjective* triple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To me it looks like a combination of two modifiers: (adj noun) and (noun adj). Sometimes (for poetic reasons) adjectives are placed *after* the noun (this also happens with certain adjectives, such as *elect* in *president elect*). So here we have *human face*, which is further modified by a post-positioned adjective:

((human face) divine) => "divine human face"

I'm not very well-versed in either Blake or Milton, but from a linguistic point of view it does not look like a specific structure to me.

UPDATE: "Miltonic structure" seems to refer to the verse patterns, rather than grammar, see http://www.theodora.com/encyclopedia/s2/sonnet.html:

> Hence this critic, like William Sharp, divides all English sonnets into four groups: (I) sonnets of Shakespearean structure; (2) sonnets of octave and sestet of **Miltonic structure**; (3) sonnets of contemporary structure, i.e. all sonnets on the Petrarchan model in which the metrical and intellectual "wave of flow and ebb" (as originally formulated by the present writer in a sonnet on the sonnet, which has appeared in most of the recent anthologies) is strictly observed, and in which, while the rhyme-arrangement of the octave is invariable, that of the sestet is free; (4) sonnets of miscellaneous structure.

(my emphasis)

Comment: +1 for being right even before your update. This comment is just because I'd have liked to give you another upvote for debunking the proposition that *Miltonic structure* has any commonly-accepted meaning relevant to the current issue in hand.

Answer (score -1):

Its not "Miltonic Structure." This is Milton using Latinate structure in the model of classical epic poetry. In Latin its not uncommon to sandwich a noun between two adjectives that describe it.